# Seemingly elementary geometric problem in R^3 which requires the axiom of choice

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, axiom-of-choice

While playing with what I called "quantum matching", the following problem arose: construct a map $F$ from the unit sphere $S_2$ in $R^3$ to itself such that $F(X)$ is orthogonal to $X$ plus has one of the properties:

1. *Strong*: if 3 vectors $X_1,X_2, X_3$ are independent then 3 vectors $F(X_1), F(X_2), F(X_3)$ are also independent.
2. *Weak*: if 3 vectors $X_1,X_2, X_3$ are orthogonal then  3 vectors $F(X_1), F(X_2), F(X_3)$ are independent.

It is not hard to prove that such maps with the Strong property don't exist. I proved the existence of such maps satisfying the Weak property, but my proof uses the Axiom of Choice and some version of the Continuum Hypothesis. Granted the maps I am after supposed to be bad,
at least discontinuous.

My question:

> Are things like Axiom of Choice really needed here?

The discussion and proofs are in http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0201022

Comment: Are you using $S_4$ for the two dimensional unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$? That is strange.

Comment: Sorry, just a typo.

Comment: I couldn't find the proof of the impossibility with Strong property in your arxiv manuscript. Could you please elaborate it or giving a reference?

Comment: Also, you missed a backslash in the 11th equation (`rho` instead of `\rho`).

Comment: It seems that you are essentially using the following fact: There exists a well-ordering of $S_2$ such that every initial segment is a measure zero set; while this follows from the Continuum Hypothesis, it also follows from Martin's Axiom (of course we use choice here). Formally speaking Martin's Axiom follows from the Continuum Hypothesis in a trivial way (it speaks on cardinalities essentially between $\aleph_0$ and $\frak c$, and under CH there are none). So one can really say that this a theorem of MA, rather than CH.

Comment: Yazdegerd: The proof is in Proposition 2.8.

Comment: Asaf: thanks, as I said, some kind of CH. My question is really AC, more generally whether axioms are needed here at all.

Comment: Must such an $F$ be discontinuous?

Comment: @AndrejBauer: If $F(X)$ is orthogonal to $X$ then $F$ is a unit tangent vector field on $S_2$.  The hairy ball theorem asserts that it cannot be continuous.

Comment: Asaf: I actually need measure zero(or some other "meagerness") on 2D tangents.

Comment: The Borel sets of any two Polish spaces are the same. It's not hard to show that as measure spaces there is a measurable isomorphism between the line and the plane. So this is really the same thing. I understand that this is a question about choice, and so my comment is not an answer, it's a comment. Your proof is not really using CH, it's using something much weaker which itself follows from MA.

Comment: Sure! But as you pointed yourself it is about choice. I remember when doing the stuff in 2001-2002, I thought that there is a possibility to put this map into the Tarski System of Geometry and to get something constructive from that.

Comment: Dear Prof Gurvits, I made some cosmetic changes to the questions. I hope that's ok.